# intellij function parameters are underlined

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6

Weird to see and figure out, I am trying to remove these underlines. I guess they are present due to wrong language support or some other issue, but I simply cant remove them. Any guess on why they are and how can i remove them?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's actually part of the default color scheme for JavaScript. You can change it easily though:

File → Settings → Editor > Colors & Fonts > JavaScript
Then find "Parameter" in the list of styled elements, and on the right side is a checkbox for "Effects", simply disable this and save and you will no longer have underlined parameter names.

[image: example]

Depending on your version of IntelliJ, you may have to save a copy of the default theme first because they didn't always let you overwrite the built in ones.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, because that's part of what SO is for, from the help center: "but if your question generally covers … software tools commonly used by programmers." And plus, it's harder to find help if you don't know what you're looking for, here the asker thought it was caused by conflicting language support.